# Задача на перестановки

Tags: c++, алгоритм, stl

Есть структура данных типа:

```
typedef int MyType; // какой-то тип, int - для примера
typedef stf::vector<std::vector<MyType>> Matrix

    Matrix m = {
       {1,2,3},
       {4,5},
       {6,7}
    }
```

Задача - получить на выходе структуру вида

```
{
   {1,4,6},
   {1,4,7},
   {2,4,6},
   ...
   {3,4,7},
   {3,5,6},
   {3,5,7}
}
```

Т.е. список всех различных векторов, в которых 0-й элемент из нулевой строки, 1-й из первой, i-й из i-й строки исходной "матрицы". Длинна каждого вектора равна количеству строк входящей структуры. Количество векторов = `l(0)*l(1)*...*l(N-1)`, где N - количество входящих строк, l(i) - длинна i-й строки. И да, строки могут быть различной длины. Все варианты для входящей структуры `{{1,2},{3,4}}`: `{{1,3},{1,4},{2,3},{2,4}`.

Задачу я решил (понятно, что при больших размерах векторов хранить в памяти результат накладно) следующим образом:

```
template <typename T> class Permutator
{
   Permutator(std::vector<std::vector<T>> data) { /* ... */ }
   std::vector<T> next() { /* ... */ }
   bool end() const { /* возвращает признак перебора всех перестановок */ }
   void start() { /* обнуляет перестановки - next() вернет {1,4,5} */ } 
}
```

Использование:

```
Permutator<MyType> p(m); // m - смотри выше
while (!p.end()) {
   std::vector<MyType> v = p.next();
   // что-то делаем с v
}
```

Вопрос, собственно в следующем, **есть ли в STL что-то подобное?**

Comment: Не могу придумать, как сюда применить `next_permutations`. У меня кода-то получилось <60 строк, с O(n) по памяти (для матрицы n x m). Без рекурсии. Сложность next - O(1). Да и факториальная сложность пугает. Просто, может в STL это уже есть, а я не знаю...

Comment: @andy.37 во-первых, это не перестановки, поэтому факториальной сложности тут не будет, а размещения с повторениями, хоть и в странной форме. Поэтому количество будет равно произведению длин строк матрицы. Во-вторых, если вам нужны все такие варианты, то за меньшее число шагов вы этого не добьетесь, и это абсолютно нормально. А вот про STL ничего сказать не могу, но очень сомневаюсь в наличии того что вы хотите.